# Como editar tabelas no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estou com um problema em uma tabela que fiz em html e javascript. 
A pagina é composta por 3 campos input que com o valor inserido é encaminhado para a tabela abaixo.

Porem eu gostaria de conseguir editar os itens da tabela sem precisar excluir e inserir de novo.

Será que há algum meio de mandar os valores de volta para o input para que eu possa edita-lo?

**PS:**

Eu fiz a remoção com um campo checkbox. que pega a linha e deleta, talvez de pra usar esse checkbox.

```js
var itens = 0;

function adicionarItem() {
  itens += 1;

  var refNome = document.querySelector("#nome").value;
  var refCpf = document.querySelector("#cpf").value;
  var refRg = document.querySelector("#rg").value;

  var usuarioTr = document.createElement("tr");
  usuarioTr.className = itens %2 == 0 ? "linha1": "linha2";
  var selec = document.createElement('td');
  selec.className = 'usr';
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  input.className = 'check';
  selec.appendChild(input);
  var nomeTd = document.createElement("td");
  var cpfTd = document.createElement("td");
  var rgTd = document.createElement("td");

  nomeTd.textContent = refNome;
  cpfTd.textContent = refCpf;
  rgTd.textContent = refRg;

  usuarioTr.appendChild(selec);
  usuarioTr.appendChild(nomeTd);
  usuarioTr.appendChild(cpfTd);
  usuarioTr.appendChild(rgTd);    

  var tabela = document.querySelector("#tabela");

  tabela.appendChild(usuarioTr);
  }

function removerItem() {
  ckList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  ckList.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (ckList[index].checked) el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  });

  if (itens > 0) 
    itens -= 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Cadastro de usuário</h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<section>
  <form>
    <div class="inputs"> 
      <div class="inside">
        <label for="nome">*Nome:</label>
        <input class="inp" id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome aqui" autofocus/>
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
        <label for="cpf">*CPF:</label>
        <input class="inp" id="cpf" name="cpf" type="number" placeholder="Digite seu CPF" />
      </div>
      <div class="inside">
        <label for="rg">*RG:</label>
        <input class="inp" id="rg" name="rg" type="number" placeholder="Digite seu RG" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="botoes">
      <button clas="bot" id="adicionarBotao" onclick="adicionarItem()" type="button">Adicionar</button>
      <button clas="bot" id="excluirBotao" onclick="removerItem()" type="button">Excluir</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>
<div class="tabelas">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Selecionar</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>CPF</th>
        <th>RG</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabela">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, pode ser que seja um pouco mais complicado que isso. O intuito desta tabela e deste formulário é trabalhar com um banco de dados?

Comment: Na verdade acho que depois será isso, pois simplesmente meu chefe chegou e falou faça essa tela. kkkkk

Comment: Já considerou a possibilidade de utilizar plugins como este: [http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-In-line-Editing-Plugin-For-jQuery-Quick-Edit/](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-In-line-Editing-Plugin-For-jQuery-Quick-Edit/)

Comment: Eu ainda nao sei como usar kkk, é para ser uma tela simples pois eu estou no inicio da faculdade e do estágio, e como é engenharia de software demora um pouco mais para pegar programação. Então essa tela tem que ser o mais pura possivel (html, JavaScript e Css). Tudo feito na mão.

Comment: Ou poderias já utilizar por exemplo este [https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row) pois já tem a requisição ajax para o seu back-end (seja qual for) para manipular o banco de dados.

Comment: Entendo, mas se for tão simples assim, sabes que os dados não serão salvos né? Até poderias armazenar os dados no navegador, mas teria o risco de perde-los facilmente. Quando tiver um tempinho, analisa este tutorial.[https://codepen.io/manolof/post/angularjs-todo-save-data-to-localstorage-or-to-txt-file-using-php#local](https://codepen.io/manolof/post/angularjs-todo-save-data-to-localstorage-or-to-txt-file-using-php#local) Pode ser que ti ajude. infelizmente não posso fazer a solução para você agora... exigiria um tempinho.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado, e seria isso mesmo, sem salvar os dados (uma aplicação até então inutil).

Answer (score 1):

Caro, editei um código que eu já tinha aqui no PC e adaptei a sua necessidade, com os valores de Nome, CPF e RG.
Agora é só ler para entender e alterar o style conforme sua necessidade...

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="table_script.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    td {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    table{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table id="data_table" >
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>CPF</th>
                <th>RG</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_cpf"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_rg"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Adicionar"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script>
        function edit_row(no) {
            document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "block";

            var name = document.getElementById("nome_row" + no);
            var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf_row" + no);
            var rg = document.getElementById("rg_row" + no);

            var name_data = name.innerHTML;
            var cpf_data = cpf.innerHTML;
            var rg_data = rg.innerHTML;

            name.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='name_text" + no + "' value='" + name_data + "'>";
            cpf.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='cpf_text" + no + "' value='" + cpf_data + "'>";
            rg.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='rg_text" + no + "' value='" + rg_data + "'>";
        }

        function save_row(no) {
            var name_val = document.getElementById("name_text" + no).value;
            var cpf_val = document.getElementById("cpf_text" + no).value;
            var rg_val = document.getElementById("rg_text" + no).value;

            document.getElementById("nome_row" + no).innerHTML = name_val;
            document.getElementById("cpf_row" + no).innerHTML = cpf_val;
            document.getElementById("rg_row" + no).innerHTML = rg_val;

            document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
        }

        function delete_row(no) {
            document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
        }

        function add_row() {
            var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name").value;
            var new_cpf = document.getElementById("new_cpf").value;
            var new_rg = document.getElementById("new_rg").value;

            var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
            var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
            var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='nome_row" +
                table_len + "'>" + new_name + "</td><td id='cpf_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_cpf +
                "</td><td id='rg_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_rg + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" +
                table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len +
                ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len +
                "' value='Salvar' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len +
                ")'> <input type='button' value='Deletar' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len +
                ")'></td></tr>";

            document.getElementById("new_name").value = "";
            document.getElementById("new_cpf").value = "";
            document.getElementById("new_rg").value = "";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Montei uma tabela básica, e coloque um botão para adicionar linha.
Depois chamo a função que no caso adiciona um evento Double Click em cada celular que adiciona um input e quando sair do input o valor do input vai pra tabela.

```
    function adicinarlinha(){
var Tabela = document.getElementById("tb01");
var Nlinha = Tabela.rows.length;
var Linha = tabela.insertRow(Nlinha);
var CPF = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
var Nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
Linha.insertCell(i);}

Tabela.rows[Nlinha].cells[0].innerHTML=Nlinha
Tabela.rows[Nlinha].cells[1].innerHTML=CPF
Tabela.rows[Nlinha].cells[2].innerHTML=Nome

AdicionarEdicao()
}


function AdicionarEdicao() {
    var rows = document.getElementById("tb01").rows;
   for(var c = 0;c < rows.cells.length;c++){
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {                        
        var ID = rows.length+i+c; 
        
        rows[i].cells[c].ondblclick= function(){ return function(){
              var Linha = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
              var Valor = this.innerHTML
              var k =this.parentNode.cellIndex;
              var ID = k+Valor+Linha;           


                this.innerHTML ="<input type='text'" + "id='"+ID + "' onfocusout='salvarlinha(this)' />"
               document.getElementById(ID).value = Valor             
               
       
        };}(rows[i].cells[c]);
    }}
}

function salvarlinha(linha){                
              var i=linha.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
              var j=linha.parentNode.cellIndex;            
             
              var Valor = linha.value;
                   
             document.getElementById('tb01').rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = Valor;            


}
```

```
    CPF - <input id="cpf" /><br/>
    Nome R$ <input id="nome" /><br/> 
    <button  id="btns" onclick="AdicionarEdicao()">Salvar</button>

    <table id="tb01" >

      <thead>
        <tr class="centered">             
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>CPF</th>        
          <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```