# Como eu faço para atualizar os valores das colunas de uma tabela em tempo de execução utlizando javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma tabela com as colunas id, quant, preco e total,
a tabela é dinamica, e quando o usuario alterar a quantidade ou o preco
eu preciso atualizar o total que é a quantidade multiplicada pelo preco,
mas eu nao consigo fazer isso, eu ja consegui montar a tabela dinamicamente
e preencher os valores mas ainda nao consigo atualizar os campos.

```js
var id = "";
var quant = "";
var preco = "";
var total = "";

//Funcao adiciona uma nova linha na tabela
function adicionaLinha(idTabela) {
  var tabela = document.getElementById(idTabela);
  var numeroLinhas = tabela.rows.length;
  var linha = tabela.insertRow(numeroLinhas);
  var celula1 = linha.insertCell(0);
  var celula2 = linha.insertCell(1);
  var celula3 = linha.insertCell(2);
  var celula4 = linha.insertCell(3);
  var itemDinamico = 'id_item' + numeroLinhas;
  var quantDinamico = 'quant' + numeroLinhas;
  var precoDinamico = 'preco' + numeroLinhas;
  celula1.innerHTML = itemDinamico; // Item
  celula2.innerHTML = "<input name=" + quantDinamico + "'" + " value='1' onchange='update(this)' type='number' id=" + quantDinamico + ">";
  celula3.innerHTML = "<input name=" + precoDinamico + "'" + " value='1' onchange='update(this)' type='number' id=" + precoDinamico + ">";
  celula4.innerHTML = "1"; // Total
}

function update(strlinha) {
  console.log(strlinha);
  // Aqui eu deveria conseguir ler as colunas e somar, mas nao consigo.    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr role="row">
        <th>
          Item
        </th>
        <th>
          Quant
        </th>
        <th>
          Preco
        </th>
        <th>
          Total
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="adicionaLinha('tbl')">Adicionar</button>
</body>
```

Comment: `onchange='update(this)` isso não funciona dentro de um contro que ainda não existe no DOM. Deve associar o evento depois dele ser inserido ao DOM, por exemplo usando `addEventListener`

Comment: Ricardo, o this do addEventListener retorna a tabela inteira em formato html. Mas eu não sei como manipular a tabela dentro do JS.

Comment: o this não pode retornar a tabela, o this devolve uma referencia para o elemento que disparou o evento, no seu caso é o input, pq o `onchange` é disparado input

Comment: Ricardo, preciso marcar como respondido e voce fez apenas um comentario, queria pontuar voce pela gentileza e atenção. Obrigado.

Comment: Ricardo, se vc responder como resposta eu posso marcar vc e voce ganhará pontos porque eu resolvi com sua explicação: OBRIGADO demais. Valeu pela rapidez na resposta.

Comment: olá Emilio, publiquei uma resposta com alguns detalhes e um exemplo do calculo dinâmico para ajudar outras pessoas

Comment: oww...obrigado! Já marquei como respondido. Sua resposta foi muito profissional. Por isso tem 22mil pontos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado, o elemente criado dinamicamente não deve ter os eventos declarados "inline", tipo "onclick=...", devemos associar os eventos (click, blur, etc) após adicionar o elemento ao DOM, para isso podemos usar [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Para um exemplo simples, podemos criar todos os elemento com a mesma classe, e registrar todos a partir da mesma classe. Para evitar "re-registrar" os mesmos eventos aos elementos já existentes, podemos usar [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) de forma semelhante antes de registrar, assim:

```
elem.removeEventListener('click', update);
elem.addEventListener('click', update);
```

Onde, `elem` é o elemento, e "update" é o nome da função que será executada no "click".

Aqui e exemplo, adaptando o código da pergunta:

```js
var id = "";
var quant = "";
var preco = "";
var total = "";

//Funcao adiciona uma nova linha na tabela
function adicionaLinha(idTabela) {
  var tabela = document.getElementById(idTabela);
  var numeroLinhas = tabela.rows.length;
  var linha = tabela.insertRow(numeroLinhas);
  var celula1 = linha.insertCell(0);
  var celula2 = linha.insertCell(1);
  var celula3 = linha.insertCell(2);
  var celula4 = linha.insertCell(3);
  var itemDinamico = 'id_item' + numeroLinhas;
  var quantDinamico = 'quant' + numeroLinhas;
  var precoDinamico = 'preco' + numeroLinhas;
  celula1.innerHTML = itemDinamico; // Item
  celula2.innerHTML = "<input name=" + quantDinamico + "'" + " value='1' class='update-input input-quant' type='number' id=" + quantDinamico + ">";
  celula3.innerHTML = "<input name=" + precoDinamico + "'" + " value='1' class='update-input input-preco' type='number' id=" + precoDinamico + ">";
  celula4.innerHTML = "1"; // Total
  celula4.classList.add("resultado")
  
  // pega todos os inputs pela class "update-input"
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".update-input");
  
  inputs.forEach(elem => {
    // remove e associa o evento click à function "update"
    elem.removeEventListener('click', update);
    elem.addEventListener('click', update);
});
}

function update(e) {
  var elem = e.target; // elemento que disparou o evento
  var tr = elem.closest("tr"); // a TR onde o elemento está
  
  // a partir da TR, pega os outros elementos pelas suas respectivas classes
  var quant = tr.querySelector(".input-quant").value;
  var preco = tr.querySelector(".input-preco").value;
  var resultado = tr.querySelector(".resultado")
  
  // ATENÇÃO: para fins de exemplo, não valida se são números válidos
  resultado.innerHTML = Number(quant) * Number(preco);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr role="row">
        <th>
          Item
        </th>
        <th>
          Quant
        </th>
        <th>
          Preco
        </th>
        <th>
          Total
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="adicionaLinha('tbl')">Adicionar</button>
</body>
```

Note que:

- adicionei classes aos elementos para ficar fácil de selecioná-los
- como comentei, a função recebe por parâmetro o evento disparado, e para obter o elemento que disparou o evento, usei `.target`
- a partir do elemento é possível navegar no DOM, indo por exemplo até a `TR` onde estão os elementos, e depois localizar cada elemento
- usei a TR como "pivot" para pegar os outros elementos, isso para alterar o que há na linha em questão, porque se usarmos `document.getElement....` vamos pegar todos os elementos, e nao é isso que pretendemos
- por fim, atualizei a quantidade, e não validei os valores. Note que é necessário validar se são valores válidos antes de fazer o cálculo

Answer (score -1):

[Como editar tabelas no JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231926/como-editar-tabelas-no-javascript)

Como Marcos Alexandre descreve neste post, foi o que mais se encaixou para mim.

```
 function save_row(no) {
        var name_val = document.getElementById("name_text" + no).value;
        var cpf_val = document.getElementById("cpf_text" + no).value;
        var rg_val = document.getElementById("rg_text" + no).value;

        document.getElementById("nome_row" + no).innerHTML = name_val;
        document.getElementById("cpf_row" + no).innerHTML = cpf_val;
        document.getElementById("rg_row" + no).innerHTML = rg_val;

        document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
    }
```

Você também pode facilitar sua vida colocando um ID em cada e modificando quando necessita a linha exemplo:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Idade</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td id='nome1'>João</td>
        <td id='idade1'>20</td>
        <tr>
        <td id='nome2'>Maria</td>
        <td id='idade2'>20</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Assim sempre você sempre vai saber que no caso seria coluna + numeroLinha. **Gambiarrinha**.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo e atenção. Vou usar suas dicas. Obrigado!